# How can I use NServiceBus with a database instead of MSMQ

Tags: nservicebus

Is it possible to use NServiceBus with a database as the queue storage instead of MSMQ?  If so, how can I get started and what are the pros and cons of using a database instead of MSMQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use something other than MSMQ you'll have to plug in your own ITransport.  I would take a look at the NSB Contrib project on GitHub, there is an implementation of of ITransport for the SQL Server Broker(messaging).

The cons I see for using a database includes cost and maintenance overhead.  MSMQ comes with the OS for free and most admins have the skills to maintain it.  Once you get in a DB, you have to pay for it and find someone to maintain it.  This starts out ok, but once you get into multiple environments and things like clustering, licensing gets out of control.

Comment: Adam - thanks for the response. If I read your answer right, using a DB for queue storage is not a standard approach?  In that case, I'm off to see the MSMQ wizard... :)

Comment: Yes, the standard approach is to use a queue technology.  You are not limited to MSMQ, but that is the default approach.

Comment: the default approach for the production profile in nservicebus is to use sql server storage. the default for testing and (or can't remember exactly) development profile is to use msmq storage.

Comment: There's some confusion going on here. I'm not sure what the original intent of the question was, but there are two things going on.  I believe Adam is talking about using a SQL database to store messages, as a replacement for MSMQ.  This is far from ideal as it is not even a queuing system, so an implementation of ITransport would have to queue the database constantly for new messages. hacktick is talking about subscription storage (storing the list of queues who subscribe to a message type) which defaults to NHibernate+DB in the production profile.

Comment: My original intent was to ask about storing messages in a SQL database, which Adam answered.  http://goo.gl/xJzVL

Comment: Sorry above comment should be this: My original intent was to ask about storing messages in an SQL database, which Adam answered.  I think my motivation for asking this was being confused after reading about storing information in a database here http://goo.gl/xJzVL says "NServiceBus does allow for configuring all publishers to store their information in a physically central location, such as a database".  After reading that I had a picture of a central _message_ store in my head, not a configuration store.  Thanks for clarification all!